# Partition problem with additional constraints

Tags: algorithms, set-partition, np-complete

I have read about the partition problem a.k.a. the easiest hard problem. I am currently working on a game where there are, say, 180 players that need to be organized into 30 teams with 6 players in each team. Every player is assigned a rank (1-6) based on the skills and the previous performance results.

The problem is to create teams in such a way that all teams have equal chances to win the tournament. As naive as it might sound, but at this stage, I translate that into "the sum of ranks in each team is the same" or, obviously, "all teams have equal average team ranks".

The partition problem is NP-hard and the solution might not even exist. It's not obvious whether the problem I described above is a simplified or even harder version of this famous problem.

What are some "good enough" approaches that can work here? There are greedy and approximate solutions for the standard version, but do they apply to my problem?

Comment: A greedy algorithm would be to start with the players with the highest ranks and allocate each player in turn to a team with the lowest total rank so far (and within those to a team with the most space).  I would expect this to work in the majority of cases where there is a solution though perhaps not all of them

Comment: @Henry, thank you very much. I wrote a small script to check how it works. Looks good and obviously "good enough" to be satisfied with the generated distribution. 

I highly doubt it the players are expected to be skilled enough to question the optimality of the distribution and solve the partition problem to prove that :)